# How to convert pixels to logic pixels in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

I'm trying to build a web app using Flutter but I have a problem. If I build it using the pixels in my design everything will be bigger as in the design. Does anyone knows how to use pixels in Flutter?